C# EPPlus Get multiple but separate columns
Is there any method for getting multiple distinct columns from EPPlus in c# than this:
range = sheet.Cells["A:B,E:F"];

Update: I would like to programmatically step through the columns based on other variables like List<int[]> Columns = {[1,2],[5,6]}, rather than using hard-coded letters. I keep trying to make range.TakeColumns() work, but can't get there.

Tell us why the way you have found is no good for you

Did you try with sheet.Columns[startCol, endCol], where the pair (startCol, endCol) is each element (a two items array) present in your Columns List?

You can do something like this:
using OfficeOpenXml;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class Program
    {      
        public static void Main ()
        {
            FileInfo existingFile = new FileInfo ("01.xlsx");
            ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage (existingFile);
            ExcelWorksheet sheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets [0];

            var columnPairs = new List<int[]> () {
                new int[] { 1, 2 },
                new int[] { 4, 6 }
            };

            foreach (var pair in columnPairs)
            {
                // Get the ExcelRangeColumn delimited by this pair of columns
                var rangeColumn = sheet.Columns [pair[0], pair[1]];
                Console.WriteLine (rangeColumn.StartColumn.ToString() + " - " + rangeColumn.EndColumn.ToString());

                // Get the associated ExcelRangeBase and browse all cells
                foreach (var cell in rangeColumn.Range)
                    Console.WriteLine (cell + ": " + cell.Value);
            }
        }
    }
}

I'm printing the name and the value of each cell in each column range (for a sample sheet with 6 columns x 3 rows):
1 - 2
A1: 1
B1: 100
A2: 2
B2: 200
A3: 3
B3: 300

4 - 6
D1: -1
E1: -100
F1: -10
D2: -2
E2: -200
F2: -20
D3: -3
E3: -300
F3: -30


I would use an array or list where each element is an object with two fields (first column, end column), but that was not your question.

Thanks for this. I was hoping to avoid looping for larger data sets. I also later ran into this issue with conditional formatting multiple ranges with the same formula. Technically you're answer addresses my question as written, so +1.

Please mark the answer as accepted. You may want to open a new one and refine the loop related part. (You want to avoid the outer loop and have just one collection of separate column ranges?)

Or, if you're concerned about the inner loop, please remember that you can act directly on rangeColumn.Range, as with any other range.
